# Is there a way to import excel sheets into an existing SharePoint list when they both have different column names?

Tags: list, excel, import

I know you can import excel sheets into SharePoint, thereby creating a brand new list, but I want to import an excel sheet into an existing list and after the fact the list and excel sheets share separate column names.

For an example, the excel sheet will have something called "Additional Needs", but the list's equivalent of that column is called "Comments". They are both the same thing, just named differently.

Comment: Hi @Lasagna-Cat (a.k.a. Garfield?) please see my very thorough answer to a related question.
**Answer**: [Import/Copy/Paste Data from Excel into Existing SharePoint List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/224375/44163).

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of column names, you can't import an Excel sheet into an existing SharePoint list.

Out of the box, the best option would probably to copy and paste your content from Excel to SharePoint Quick Edit mode. But the copy and paste is far from perfect between Excel and SharePoint (you lose stuff on the way).

Another option is to go through a 3rd party software such as [SharePoint List Synchronizer](https://www.synchronizer-for-excel-and-sharepoint.com). Disclaimer: this product is edited by SoftFluent, my employer.